# Form crashes when opening

Tags: c#, forms

Whenever I open my form (the one which stuff is being sent to) it crashes because a of a certain part. The part that is breaking it is `Convert.ToInt32(txt_cost)`. Im looking to know how this should be sent to my other form without crashing the program

```
private void btn_HomepageSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValidData())
        {
            string destination = cbo_Destination.Text;

            DateTime checkIn = date_FlightDate.Value;
            frm_BookingPg frm_HomePge = new frm_BookingPg(cbo_Destination.Text, cbo_AmountOfPeople.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txt_cost));

            frm_HomePge.Show();
            this.Hide();               
        }         
    }
```

Comment: What is txt_cost ?

Comment: If its breaking on `Convert.ToInt32` the answer is easy. The input isnt an int

Comment: Looks _(based on your naming conv)_ that you're trying to convert a `TextBox` to an `int`. It should probably be `txt_cost.Text`

Comment: It changes depending on whats selected in combo boxes 'destination' and 'AmountOfPeople', but its a number

Comment: If it changes based on selection and its an int why is it called txt_cost

Comment: Wheels73 probably has the answer for you

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming you have an integer in your text box, i believe that should be

 Convert.ToInt32(txt_cost.Text)
```

if it still crashes then the value of txt_cost can't be a valid int. try the below

```
var intValue = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(txt_cost.Text, out intValue))
            {
                //do something with intValue    
            }
```

Comment: no it still crashes my program, removing that bit fixes it but i need it

Comment: @Minimarshman I don't know what you're on about but he's not telling you to remove anything. hes telling you to add .Text

Comment: I did, it crashes still. Ignore the last bit its not useful and is misleading

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

> *( Code part from the comment of [@Minimarshman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7492638/minimarshman) ) :*

```
case "ten":
    price1 = 10; 
    break;

decimal total = price * price1;
txt_cost.Text = total.ToString("c");
```

So as you can see you're converting `decimal` to `string` and then assign that into a `TextBox`'s `Text` property.

**ALWAYS** leave some margin for errors especially when you're doing software development. Meaning that you should **NEVER TRUST** that user will use your software as it was intended. Your usage of `Convert.ToInt32(txt_cost)` shows that you trust your/user data too much.

To deal with this you have to check every data that you're converting if it really is a valid data. [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) has many built-in methods/functions that will validate that and the one you should use is `decimal.TryParse` which ensures that data is valid for the type conversion.

Another thing is that you're using special format for your `ToString` (`"C"`) which indicates that it should put currency mark in the string. You have to remember to then get rid of this.

*Code explanation :*

```
decimal IfValueIsConvertibleItWillBeHeldHere = 0;
if(decimal.TryParse(txt_cost.Text.Split(' ')[0], out IfValueIsConvertibleItWillBeHeldHere)
{ 
    frm_BookingPg frm_HomePge = new frm_BookingPg(
        cbo_Destination.Text, 
        cbo_AmountOfPeople.Text, 
        (int)IfValueIsConvertibleItWillBeHeldHere // see the difference ?
    );

    frm_HomePge.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    // show some message to the user that input was invalid
}
```

*Remarks :*

Doing so leaves you with chaotic code because converting from `decimal` to `int` using explicit type conversion will trim that value. For example `decimal d = 0.5M;` explicitly converted to `int` like `int i = (int)d;` will return `0` because it trims down the part after decimal mark `.`.

You should rewrite your `frm_BookingPg` to accept `decimal` type instead of `int` type so that the value will be accurate :

```
public frm_BookingPg(string destination, string amountOfPeople, decimal cost)
```

Instead of your actual :

```
public frm_BookingPg(string destination, string amountOfPeople, int cost)
```

Comment: It is not a string, its a price that is automatically generated with two different options selected from combo boxes destination and amount of people. Destination has a set price and is then multiplied by the amount of people. Ill show the code for this if you really want

Comment: This is the maths going on as well as an example of what im using to get the values needed to perform the maths using case switch, i also cant get it to format correctly so that it will show up as code
    case "ten":
                    price1 = 10;
                    break;

            }
            decimal total = price * price1;
            txt_cost.Text = total.ToString("c");

Comment: Side note: By "trims down" I think you mean "Floors" as in `Math.Floor()`.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder By "trims down" I meant what it does. Meaning that it doesn't care about any value after the decimal mark. So even if you have something like `decimal d = 0.999999999999999999999999999M` which obviously should be `1`. After calling explicit operator to convert into `int` like `int i = (int)d;` it will return `0`.

Comment: @m.rogalski Because it floors the value, that is what floors does. Although I'm not entirely sure what floor does on negative numbers.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `Math.Floor` called with parameter `-0.999999999999999999999999999M` will return `-1` but casting it explicitly like :`int i = (int)-0.999999999999999999999999999M` will return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing 
`Convert.ToInt32(txt_cost)`
with just an int32 literal value?

As follows:-

```
frm_BookingPg frm_HomePge = new frm_BookingPg(cbo_Destination.Text, cbo_AmountOfPeople.Text, 1234);
```

does it still crash?

Comment: You im still learning and im not exactly sure what im supposed to type in there, could you show me the code you think i should use? thanks

Comment: Change txt_cost to a number is what hes saying. eg. `(5)`

Comment: i see what you mean but the problem is that its a changing value depending on user input

Comment: Glad you understand, but just for test purposes, does doing as I suggest prevent the code from crashing?  If so, then it will help you narrow down where the problem lies.